# Does Java GC dellocates null elements of an array?

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection

I wanted to "delete" some elements of an array,when I set them to null those elements didn't showed up in when I tried to print it,do they get "deleted by garbage collector or the println method just ignores null values?For example:

```
this.E = new String[3];
E[0]="blue";
E[1]="red";
E[1]="gray";
this.E[0] = null;
for(int i = 0 ; i < E.length ; i++)
    System.out.println(E[i]);
```

That code outputs just red and gray,so blue is dellocated of the memory or the null value was just ignored as it doesn't represents anything?

Comment: Would you please put here some code and specify your question in more detail?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Null is null.

Comment: When I attempt to print a null it outputs "null". Could you show the code that reproduces this (although to your question nulls are equivalent to nothing, they are not garbage collected)

Comment: If `String[t]` is null `this.E` will be set to null

Comment: No, they are not ignored by GC if that element is in an array which is allocated and is in memory as long as the program is running. Also null value of an array element is not ignored by System.out.println and should print null string.

Comment: I added some code sample,thanks :)

Comment: It typically will be eligible for GC at this point, if that is the only reference to it. But what you are seeing is not related to GC. Yours is to do with the `null`, since `E[0]` does not any longer refer to the string "blue". This ignores optimizations that the JVM might perform for the string "blue" - string interning or string pool or such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value stays in the memory,GC would need to dellocate the entire array to do what yo want

Answer (score 1):

It depends on other threads too. if deleted object is referenced by any live thread it can't be garbage collected

Comment: Threads are an unnecessary complication in an answer, all that matters are other references